# Validate number using regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex, string, gxt

Can anyone help me for validation of numbers like:

> 1,478.25

Special characters like `.` And `,` are only allowed

> ***(@#$_&-+()/*"':;!?~`|•√π÷×¶={} not allowed )***.

This is the regex I have tried so far:

```
/^[0-9]+([,][0-9]+)?$/
```

Your help will be appreciated.
Valid number are 123.45    1,234.5 and 0.01

Comment: /^[0-9]+([,][0-9]+)?$/

Comment: go with /^[0-9]+([,][0-9]+)?$/

Comment: Not working Mavericks

Comment: It should allow only single dot

Comment: You said "numbers like", what other forms should be accepted? Is `123` number valid or should it be `123.00`? Is `1,2345.00` valid? Or `.01`? Do you want to accept only two decimal places or can it change?

Comment: Yes number u have mentioned are valid @pshemo

Comment: Update your post to include rules you use to decide what is valid and what is not.

Comment: "Yes number u have mentioned are valid" I also mentioned `1,2345.00` which has four digits after `,`. So can we assume that `,` can have any number of digits after it like `1,2,3,4,5,6.00`? Would such number be valid or there is some *rule* which invalidates it? If so what rule is it?

Comment: @pshemo 1,2,3,4.00 is not valid...my current rule is I just want only one decimal value and accept comma..in text field.

Comment: @VaibhavKatwate only one digit and one comma?

Comment: @sejal rudani... Only one dot of decimal..

Comment: @VaibhavKatwate  multiple comma?

Comment: @sejal Rudani ...yes multiple commas

Comment: @VaibhavKatwate please check my ans for single dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the regex you need: [`^(\\d{1,3},)*(\\d{1,3})(.\\d{1,3})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/ErWGqb/2) along with the `global` and `multiline` flags.

This is how should be your code:

```
final String regex = "^(\\d{1,3},)*(\\d{1,3})(\\.\\d{1,3})?$";
final String string = "1,478.25\n"
     + "1,450\n"
     + "48.10\n"
     + "145.124.14";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);


while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
}
```

This is [a live **Demo**](https://ideone.com/MDaeve).

Answer (score 0):

Please use below regular expression to validate numeric value with one decimal and multiple comma

```
      String num="1,335.25";

        String exp ="^[-+]?[\\d+([,]\\d+)]*\\.?[0-9]+$";

        if(num.matches(exp)){  
            System.out.println("valid number");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Not a valid number");
        }
```

Please check this one.

Comment: Please check edited ans for multiple comma and single dot

Comment: Yes if I put number as 0.01

Comment: Thanks sejal for your help as my reputation is not up to mark I am not able to mark ans as correct...thank you once again...

Comment: currently I am facing issue for entering negative values can you please help me...

Answer (score 0):

I think this regex is what you need

```
^\d{1,}(,\d+)?\.\d+$
```